# How to set part of a datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I need to set just the hour of a datetime to a certain value. I know I can add it the difference to the desired value, or create a new datetime with parts from the original one, but isn't there a cleaner way? Something like:

```
declare @d datetime = '09/08/2012 09:14:55'

set @d = SETDATEPARTORSOMETHINGLIKETHAT (hour, @d, 23)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nope. It's [not listed in the available functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx). You could perhaps [write your own function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) to do it, but internally to the function, it would still be using the same basic SQL (DateAdd) you'd use anyway.

Comment: The question was 'isn't there a cleaner way?', and his answer is 'no', so I guess strictly speaking it is the objective answer, even if not the most useful (but not useless at all, since I was convinced that there would be a function somewhere).

Comment: @AaronBertrand -  It's answering the question he asked "Isn't there a cleaner way?"  He already stated in his question: "I know I can add it the difference to the desired value, or create a new datetime with parts from the original one" which was what you answered.  He asked, pecifically, is there a cleaner way.  Creating a function to do the work is a cleaner way, but it is using the same method he mentioned under the hood.    "No" ***is*** the answer to the question.  You just told him what he already said he knew how to do in code.

Comment: Perhaps, then, this question should be moved to the Philosophy.SE beta since its format is so esoteric. As it stands, since it's on SO, we should strive for answers that solve *actual* problems.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I don't want to argue, but asking if there's a more efficient way (and if so, what is it) is perfectly valid.  A huge portion of the time, the answer is yes.  This was just one of the rare cases where the answer is no.  His question was fine, and your answer was good.  I really don't see why you're so bent out of shape.  You're getting plenty of upvotes (including one from me) and your answer will be helpful to future users.  Knowning what's not possible with a certain technology is an important thing to know.  I'm sorry to have offended you.

Comment: And I did suggest writing a function using the knowledge he already has.  In combination with your answer, that will make it more efficient for him in the future... But again, I don't want to argue.

Comment: You haven't offended me. I just thought your answer should have been a comment, that's all. It's not a very useful answer to future readers who want to know *how* to set a datetime to a specific hour (or minute, or week, or month) with or without a built-in function that does it directly. Remember this site isn't *just* about solving the OP's problem, it's about helping other users solve similar problems as well.

Comment: And that's why I voted you up.  Your answer ***is*** useful for that.  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TargetHour TINYINT = 23;

DECLARE @d datetime = '09/08/2012 09:14:55';
SET @d = DATEADD(HOUR, @TargetHour - DATEPART(HOUR, @d), @d);
SELECT @d;
```

Result:

```
2012-09-08 23:14:55.000
```

(And yes, this will work if the @TargetHour is *less* than the current hour, e.g. 5 or 7.)

I'd be very careful though about using ambiguous and error-prone formats like m/d/y. Case in point: I don't even know if you meant September 8th or August 9th, and SQL Server isn't going to know either - it needs to use regional settings etc. to figure it out, and if you give your code to someone with different settings, it will generate an error or, even worse, accept the wrong date silently. You should use:

```
DECLARE @d datetime = '2012-09-08T09:14:55';
```

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)